# OpenCV Clang mat.hpp error: call to member function 'ptr' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, opencv, clang

I have an error when I compile my program that uses OpenCV just by including #include , which is:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp:46:
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4826:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:2248:42: error: call to member function 'ptr' is ambiguous
{ return (const _Tp*)((SparseMat*)this)->ptr(i0, false, hashval); }
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:3507:12: note: candidate function
    uchar* ptr(int i0, bool createMissing, size_t* hashval=0);
           ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:3509:12: note: candidate function
    uchar* ptr(int i0, int i1, bool createMissing, size_t* hashval=0);
           ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:3513:12: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to
      'const int *' for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &
    uchar* ptr(const int* idx, bool createMissing, size_t* hashval=0);
           ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:3511:12: note: candidate function not viable: requires at least 4 arguments, but 3 were
      provided
    uchar* ptr(int i0, int i1, int i2, bool createMissing, size_t* hashval=0);
```

I tried multiple (recent) versions of OpenCV but in my case none of them work. Does OpenCV officially not support Clang, or is it an error I should report ? 
I use Linux (ubuntu 13.04) and I use clang 3.2-1.

Comment: Ok, so I think we can say that OpenCV does not fully (and not at all in certain cases) support Clang.

Answer (score -1):

I got same error recently on my mac. (Jan-2016)

The procedure to get the error is following:

1. install opencv using brew

   `brew install opencv`

   In this case, brew installs gcc before opencv and compiles opencv using gcc NOT clang.
   gcc is installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0/bin/`
2. I made my program and try to compile with CMake using default option. The cmake tries to use clang as complier : it's location is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc`
3. Because opencv's compiler and program's compiler are different, it produces error.

So, I tried to set compiler as gcc in cmake

`set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER   /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0/bin/gcc-5 )
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0/bin/gcc-5 )`

Then, I passed that error.